Stubborn bath seal
I’ve tried caulking, the seal many times, including buying this plastic sealer. I’ve also tried glue and nothing seems to work. I’m wondering if there are any recommended approaches out there to fixing this? Other than taking the entire panel down and replacing it.


what is the problem?

What's the crap under that while seal thing?

Does the tub move relative to the wall panel when filled with water or if a person stands in it to shower?

Problem is, I can’t get any caulking or rubber sealer to stick.
The crap under it is caulking or glue that I used to try to get it to stick before. Each time I reapplied I did clean it off. So it didn’t look like that when I put the seal on there.
No, the tub does not move.
